# Is salesforce API works as per the login user profile permission?

Tags: api

I am logged in as administrator and download the salesforce API (WSDL).

I am logged in as sales agent and download the salesforce API (WSDL).

Both users are having different profile permission. when downloading the API, it will work with the profile level permission or both are having same permission?

Regards,

Sathish

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce API respects object-level and field-level security configured in the user interface. You can access objects and fields only if the logged-in user's permissions and access settings allow such access. For e.g, fields that are not visible to a given user are not returned in a query() or describeSObjects() call. An organization's Salesforce administrator controls the availability of various features and  views by configuring profiles and permission sets, and assigning users to them. 
To access the Salesforce API to issue calls and receive the call results, a user must be granted the “API Enabled” permission. And Client applications can query or update only those objects and fields to which they have access via the permissions of the logged-in user.

To investigate data access issues you can inspect the WSDL for the Objects.